# HTML Lists with image bullets using clip property

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create HTML lists with image bullets using the clip property? I've been trying to get it to work but I can't seem to get it right.

I would appreciate some assistance.

Here is my initial HTML code:

```
<div class="my-clip-list">
<ul>
   <li class="one">One</li>
   <li class="two">Two</li>
   <li class="three">Three</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And my initial CSS:

```
.my-clip-list {position: relative;}
.my-clip-list ul {position: absolute;}
.my-clip-list ul li {line-height: 24px; content:url([url_of_sprite]);}
.my-clip-list ul li.one {clip: rect(top right bottom left)}
.my-clip-list ul li.two {clip: rect(top right bottom left)}
.my-clip-list ul li.three {clip: rect(top right bottom left)}
```

I did this but it doesn't seem to be working. Please note that I have put in the generic info for clip property, in my actual CSS I have real pixel values. This is just to illustrate what I'm doing.

Kindly assist if you can.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can it be because the li items themselves aren't positioned "absolute", just the UL? Just guessing here from the documentation/references.

Comment: This is mostly correct. However, since OP is targeting the bullets, this won't work even if the `li` are set to absolute. He will need to use `::before` or `::after` to get this effect and disable bullets with `list-style: none`